# GWT-Google web Toolkit-DialogBox

Tags: gwt

I have doubt regarding GWT .In Gwt if i click one button than it shows one dialog box at th same time the form outside the dialog box disabled.What component can be used for this task?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

So, you want to open a popup dialog box, and at the same time disable the rest of the page until the user closes the dialog box?

If so, you can simply use gwt's DialogBox.

Use the constructor with the autohide flag set to false, and the box will not close until the user responds, thus disabling the rest of the page. If you want to make this even more clear, use the glass effect:

```
yourBox.setGlassEnabled(true);
```

You can also use the PopupPanel directly and build your own custom dialog box.

Now, if I got it wrong and you want to disable the form so it remains disabled after the popup, just disable it in the *onClick* handler of the button that opens the box.